# Oval - object validation framework for Java

Tags: java, android, oval

```
@ValidateWithMethod(methodName = "isValidPostalCode", parameterType = String.class)
private String _postalCode;

private boolean isValidPostalCode(String _postalCode) {
   boolean status = false;
   if (this.getTypeEnum() == 2) {
       if ((this.getPostal_code() == null)|| (this.getPostal_code() == "")) {
           status = true;
       }
   }
   return status;
}
```

I'm developing an Android Application with the use of `Oval 1.7` as well. I'm trying to validate an Entity class (property validation), with the use of `@ValidateWithMethod`, but it's not working, I guess its not recognizing the method, all other annotations like `@MaxLength(value = 12)` are working. Please help...

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

`private boolean isValidPostalCode(String postalCode) {`

`if (postalCode == null || postalCode.isEmpty()) {`

**EDIT:** You should also add `ignoreIfNull = false` to the annotation. see http://oval.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/oval/constraint/ValidateWithMethod.html#ignoreIfNull()